Creating a Low Internal Resistance Switch Using N-Type MOSFET
I am trying to use an IRF640N N-type MOSFET as a low-side switch for a small device. While the concept seems straightforward, I'm encountering issues when I move from simulation to a real-world breadboard setup.
In my Proteus simulation, everything works as expected. However, on the breadboard, I'm seeing a significant voltage drop across the MOSFET when running 2A through the drain. Additionally, the MOSFET heats up rapidly and seems like it can't sustain the load for more than 10 minutes due to excessive heat.
I'm struggling to understand why this is happening and how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the picture of my circuit.

Figure 1: Here is the Proteus simulation picture


Figure 2: Here is the picture before I started my load cell


Figure 3: Here is the picture when load cell starts to use 2A current


The IRF640N is not particularly low resistance (0.15 ohm with Vgs = 10V). It is not specified for Vgs below 10V (a common issue in misunderstandings of MOSFETs). Your supply (7.4V) is not guaranteed to give 0.15 ohm (it will be higher but by how much would be a guess).

ganjiguur amatsaihkan - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules differ from typical forums (e.g. the Q&A format). (b) You just posted an "answer" (using the input field at the bottom of the page labeled "Your Answer"), but it was still asking for more advice, and it was aimed as a reply to another answer. So it seems you probably posted that as if this was a typical forum - however that was incorrect use of the "Your Answer" input box. || If you want to reply to (or ask clarification of) an answer, that must be done using a comment on Stack Exchange.

(continued) Something written as an answer must answer the original question (in this case, yours) and should not be anything else e.g. an interim update or a reply to another answer. || Since you asked the question, the only time you would use the "Your Answer" input box is if you have solved your own problem and are giving a new, full & final solution. That doesn't apply for what you posted, so I moved it to be comments on that other answer. || Please note the site etiquette explained here and about the use of comments here.

From the  IRF640N datasheet, on page 3, we have these two graphs:

The red dots show the point on the \$V_{GS}=7V\$ line where current is 2A. Fig. 1 is good for when the transistor is cool, at 25°C, and you can see that it will develop a drain-source voltage of a little over \$V_{DS}=0.2V\$. This corresponds to a power dissipation of:
$$ P_{25} = I \times V = 2A \times 0.2V = 0.4W $$
This will obviously cause the transistor to heat up, quite slowly at first. From fig. 2 it's clear that as temperature rises, so does \$V_{DS}\$. If current is kept constant at 2A, then as \$V_{DS}\$ rises, so does power dissipation, causing the transistor to heat faster. This leads to \$V_{DS}\$ rising faster still, causing even faster heating.
If ever the temperature of the transistor were to rise to 175°C, fig 2. shows that with 2A of drain current \$V_{DS}=0.6V\$, and power would then be:
$$ P_{175} = I \times V = 2A \times 0.6V = 1.2W $$
By then, the transistor would surely be cooking itself very quickly indeed, unless you could remove that heat as quickly as it's generated, with a heatsink.
This problem occurs when drain current is kept constant, and the phenomenon is called thermal runaway. Thermal runaway generally does not occur if the load is a fixed resistance, instead of something that varies resistance to maintain constant current. That's because if the load was resistive, the voltage across it would fall as \$V_{DS}\$ rises, causing current to fall also, preventing the transistor's power dissipation from rising over time.
I think you'll have less destructive results using your programmable load in constant resistance mode instead of constant current.

Thank you for your detailed explanation. It's clear that the thermal behavior of the MOSFET is a critical factor in this scenario. Considering your insights, I'm now exploring alternative methods to control the 2A, 7.4V circuit without relying on switching frequency. One approach that comes to mind is utilizing a constant resistance load instead of a constant current load. By adjusting the resistance of the load to maintain a consistent voltage drop across it, we can potentially mitigate the thermal runaway issue you've described.

Additionally, I'm open to exploring different MOSFET options or even alternative components altogether if they offer better thermal performance or efficiency in this application. I appreciate your guidance and any further suggestions you may have on how to tackle this challenge.

@ganjiguuramatsaihkan I think you misunderstood what was the issue. You need at least 10V on the gate of that mosfet to use it as a switch. That’s all. No need to over complicate it. You can also choose a mosfet suited for your application. The one you chose makes sense for much higher voltages. For low voltages, you can easily get tiny surface mount mosfets that will switch your load and pose no thermal issues at all. Tiny parts, grain of rice sized.

To use a mosfet as a switch, the parameter that you have to check in the datasheet is: Rds(on) at the voltage that you plan to apply to the gate (Vgs).
Your mosfet won't be fully conducting at Vgs=7V.  The datasheet only mentions a Rds(on) for Vgs of 10V. So below that voltage probably it will have some resistance, drop voltage and heat up.
But if you check this one for example: IRLZ44N (Infineon Technologies)

You can see that even at 4 V it will be fully on, with a resistance of only 35 mΩ
Or this one: IRF3708 (Infineon Technologies)

13.5 mΩ at 4.5V.
